# Excel VBA drop down list in table gives data validation error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I get a data validation error in Excel 2016. I have a drop down list using the data validation list type. I want to display the full name in the drop down list, while only inserting the code number when selecting an entry. To achieve this, I wrote the macro below.

```
'Function to change drop down list full name to code number
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 1 Then
        'Return value using index...match
        selectedNum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("D2:D4"), Application.Match(Range("A2"), Range("E2:E4"), 0), 1)
        
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = selectedNum
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The error only appears when I'm using a table. Does anyone have any idea how to prevent the error from appearing? I turned off the error message in data validation too.

Please find below the pictures of the error message. I did not know how to attach my excel worksheet, otherwise I would have done so.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the validation is based on the full name (i.e. the values in column E), then you can't enter values into that cell that aren't in column E. So, trying to enter the value from column D into the validated cell will throw a validation error.

If you want to allow any value in that column (though the drop-down will still work), you should uncheck this check-box:

[image]